# How to turn .h file +dll into some kind of .Net wrapper?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, c, wrapper

How toturn .h file +dll into some kind of .Net wrapper? or something like that? (no C\C++ sources just h files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the header file, and use many implement from that dll you can use swig(http://www.swig.org/) to generate wrapper automatically. Then compile as a dll and invoke the interfaces or class from .Net code.

Or if you only use few method from the dll, just use P/Invoke.

Answer (score 1):

If its straight function calls you should be able to write down the P/Invoke calls.

If its C++ classes, writing a C++ shim DLL is a fairly easy task.

Or, use C++/CLR to write the shim in.